# Passing values form one form into another - a weird case

Tags: php, forms, post, get

Please have a look to the following code:

```
<?php

  $nomeDominio='';

  if (isset($_GET['infoDominio']))
  {          
      $nomeDominio = $_GET['nomeDominio'];
      echo "I'm getting ".$nomeDominio;
  }

  if (isset($_POST['atualizarDominio']))
  {
      echo "I'm posting ".$nomeDominio;
  }

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Test Case 99</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form name="infoDominio" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"  method="get">

            <input id="nome_dominio" type="text" name="nomeDominio" value="<?php echo $nomeDominio; ?>"/>
            <br />
            <button name="infoDominio" type="submit">Obtem informacao</button>

        </form>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" name="atualizarDominio" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $nomeDominio ?>" name="nome-dominio"/>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" name="atualizarDominio">atualizar domínio</button>

        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

You can copy/paste - it will serve as test case.

Like this, IF we **get** and then we **post**:
The value from GET ***WILL NOT*** pass into POST.

The thing is:
If we just change the action= property of the second form element to, instead of having the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], to have just action=""; 
you will notice that the value ***WILL*** pass.

My question is:
Why?

**ADDITIONAL NOTE:**
This is not something to solve. Instead, this is something to understand why is it happening this way. 
**Why**, if we change the action on the second form to *action=""*, the value stored in $nomeDominio pass from one conditional into another? The code sample can be used by itself, so you can perfectly test this very easily and see what I'm talking about.

Comment: -1 without any justification. That is rude. :(

Comment: +1, nothing wrong with this question.  Nothing worse than a silent downvoter!

Comment: @Abe Miessler: Thanks for your sense of justice. :) @All: If anyone, for any reason, happens to have this question, or puzzlement, it seems that the issue is, somehow, related with the fact that we have the button name and the form name, equal to each other, leading to inconsistencies on the browser side. - but this is NOT confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 {          
      $nomeDominio = $_GET['nomeDominio'];
      echo "I'm getting ".$nomeDominio;
  }

  if (isset($_POST['atualizarDominio']))
  {
      $nomeDominio = $_POST['nomeDominio']; //THIS HERE
      echo "I'm posting ".$nomeDominio;
  }
```

you are missing the line with comment THIS HERE

You wanted to pass the _GET['nomeDominio'] from the first form to a hidden field of the second form right? Then when we submit the SECOND form you echo nomeDominio's value again (from the second form's hidden field).
You where missing and assignement in the $_POST: $nomeDominio = $_POST['nomeDominio'];

There you go. If  you do not undesrtand I do not know how to say differently.

Comment: It's the name of the form. You can freely copy paste this code so see it for yourself.

Comment: I meant its because of that it fails. Try my fix.

Comment: @Iznogood - I will try right a way. In the meanwhile, what should I expect? What is a "fix" on this case?

Comment: I was mistaken. Look at my answer the solution is there you where missing an assignment.

Comment: @Iznogood - I test your previous suggestion, and I get the same results. I will now test your new one. :)

Comment: New one will work I am sure of it. You where never assigning $_POST['nomeDominio'] in the second form.

Comment: @Iznogood - that will work yes.. But it's defeating the all propose. The point is to pass a value from the GET conditional into the POST conditional. And what I'm stating is that: if we change the form action to action="" on the second form, it will do that. And I'm wondering why. :??

Comment: Well you are doing that. From the GEt to the hidden field back to the POST.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your answer... can you please elaborate. I'm fairly newbie on those matters. :(

Comment: @Iznogood: You wanted to pass the _GET['nomeDominio'] from the first form to a hidden field of the second form right? NO. :) I understand you perfectly. :) The issue is solved. My question was: "why am I having this" and NOT "how can I solve this". Normally however, they get mixed, but that's not my fault. Still, I found half of the answer I was looking for. ;) I was having this issue, because the FORM name had the same as the button name, leading to inconsistencies. However, that is not a fully answer. But I would take it. :s

Comment: @MEM oh well. Thats a argument to formulate yoru question better next time I guess. If I helped you accept my answer or give me a point. If you dont think I deserve it its ok too.

Comment: Sure you deserve Iznogood. The point is given. You have help me thinking on new ways to formulate this question, and dialectic always helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are being inconsistent. The top form uses `nomeDominio` for the element name, where as the bottom form uses `nome-dominio`. My hunch is that is why one shows up and the other does not, you are accessing the wrong name.

**EDIT**

Further elaboration:

```
if (isset($_POST['nomeDominio']))
{
    echo "I'm posting ".$_POST['nomeDominio'];
}
```

Replacing that code, and assuming you chose the `nomeDominio` for the name, that should work.

Comment: Thanks premiso. I'm not following however. Please have patience. I have put the same name on both. The "issue" remains exactly the same. You can copy/paste the code to see it.

Comment: Please have a look to my additional note on my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to be able to propagate the `$_GET` value even through a `POST` method. You can do this by appending the query string to the action attribute of the second `POST` form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] );?>" name="atualizarDominio" method="post">
```

EDIT: Ok, I think I understand a bit better.

In the first case, (with the second form action as `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`), you are forcing the form to post the data to the page without all the added `$_GET` data (if you look at the URL, the `$_GET` data is appended to the file name after the `?`), so when you look for `$_GET['infoDominio']`, it doesn't exist any more, and therefore `$nomeDominio` is still set to an empty string. When you send the `POST` form, the `$_POST['atualizarDominio']` IS set, and you get the `I'm posting` message, but with no value set in `$nomeDominio`.

Now when you change the action of the second form to `""`, you are telling the browser to send the user to the same page you were just on, which includes all the `$_GET` data in the URL (check it - you find the `?nomeDominio=whatever&infoDominio=` in the address bar still). When you submit the second form after having submitted the first form, all the `$_GET` data is propagated, and so `$_GET['infoDominio']` is set, `$nomeDominio` is assigned whatever value you put in the first form, and thus shows up in the page after submitting the second form.

The fact that the form name and the submit button name are the same shouldn't affect it.

If I'm still misunderstanding what you're asking, please let me know. Otherwise I hope this helps.

Comment: No you are not understanding me correctly. :) I don't want to SOLVE anything. I would like to just UNDERSTAND why it behaves like this. Have a look into Additional Note on the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have done two mistake. First Mistake

```
if (isset($_POST['atualizarDominio']))
{
  $nomeDominio = $_POST['nomeDominio']; ///Here
  echo "I'm posting ".$nomeDominio;
}
```

Second Mistake

```
<input type = "hidden" value="<?php echo $nomeDominio; ?>" name="nomeDominio"/><br/>
name="nome-dominio"   //This is another Mistake
name="nomedominio" //use it
```